# Accessing random named keys in json

Tags: python, json

Trying to access a an array that has random a key name. As I can't access the key like this, because they are always different (as they are dates ) and they don't follow any pattern :

```
for d in data:
    for y in d['nightlyDetails']['randomkeyname']:
        print(y)
```

How do I access it on this json ?

```
"checkOut": "2016-02-04",
  "sourceBusinessName": "xxxx.com",
  "folioStatusIdUserDef": "0",
  "discounts": 0,
  "reservationDate": "2015-06-30 07:13:11",
  "additionalGuestIds": [],
  "lastNightAuditDate": "0000-00-00",
  "adjustmentTotal": 0,
  "totalRent": 1280,
  "noOfSplits": 1,
  "checkoutDate": "2016-02-04 10:19:30",
  "noOfNights": 1,
  "folioNo": "44108",
  "pm_code": "",
  "arrivalAmpm": "am",
  "folioStatus": "Checked-Out",
  "checkinBy": "xxxx",
  "reservedBy": "Oboe Reservation",
  "event_training_id": "0",
  "housekeepingRuleId": "0",
  "occupancyAdults": "2",
  "nightlyDetails": {
    "2016-02-03": {
      "accountLabelId": 1,
      "accountCategoryId": 6,
      "NightlyOverrideType": "0",
      "accountCategoryType": "Add-on",
      "NightlyRoomTransferId": "0",
      "accountLabelType": " Rooms \u74e6\u5382\u623f\u95f4",
      "NightlyRateId": "196",
      "NightlyActualPrice": "1280.000000",
      "NightlydiscountType": "0",
      "NightlyOverride": "0.000000",
      "rateName": "SQ",
      "NightAuditDate": "0000-00-00",
      "NightlyPaidByGroup": "0",
      "NightlyOfferedPrice": "1280.000000",
      "Nightlydiscount": "0.00",
      "NightlyActualDiscountPrice": 1280
    }
```

Comment: Those keys aren't *"random"*, and *"they don't follow any pattern"* is clearly false; they're the dates in the booking! You could work out what they are by iterating over the `noOfNights` to the `checkoutDate`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the keys of any dictionary by calling `d.keys()` or tuples of key and value by `d.items()`.

```
for d in data:
    for (date, details) in d['nightlyDetails'].items():
        for (key, value) in details.items():
            print(date, key, value)
```

Comment: Note that `keys()[0]` will fail in 3.x: `'dict_keys' object does not support indexing`

Comment: I am on 3.x, what's the way then ?

Comment: I added an additional for-loop to my answer to avoid the indexing and to enable more than one dates. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: You can also explicitly convert the dict into a list to get an indexable list of keys: `list(d['nightlyDetails'])`